# Map List object using SQL Server and Dapper

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I'm using SQL Server and Dapper and I want to properly store my models object into database and retrieve them.

That's my model, the guid list is list of other model 'Generator' IDs.

```
public class GeneratorSet
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> GeneratorsList { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to correctly map this object to a SQL Server table and then using Dapper correctly retrieve my objects from database. The relationship is many to many (set can 'posses' many generators, and generator may be possesed by many sets).

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is your issue?

Comment: I've tried to set table row as varchar and store the list in string with each guid separated with comma. And then do some heavy mapping using dapper. But that's not looking well and professional. I'm aiming for a way to use basic dapper map like `var generatorSet = connection.QueryFirst<GeneratorSet>("SELECT * FROM GeneratorSet WHERE Id= @ID;", new { ID = Id });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the SplitOn parameter... Here is a guide;

https://taylorhutchison.github.io/2016/03/23/dapper-orm-complex-queries.html

Or just by having unique names and mapping using a lambda - using the example from the documentation (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper);

```
var sql = 
@"select * from #Posts p 
left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId 
Order by p.Id";

var data = connection.Query<Post, User, Post>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post;});
var post = data.First();

Assert.Equal("Sams Post1", post.Content);
Assert.Equal(1, post.Id);
Assert.Equal("Sam", post.Owner.Name);
Assert.Equal(99, post.Owner.Id);
```

I can't write the actual code/query as I don't know your database schema... but hopefully you get the idea?

Comment: Yes, I've managed to do what I want due to your instructions. Thanks!